"Обратная совместимость" и справка про генеративный ИИ
Теперь у нас две статьи справки про генеративный ИИ. Так получилось из-за таинственной ошибки сотрудника. Предполагается, что в ближайшем будущем недоразумение будет исправлено (да, кстати, компания начала активно просматривать запросы со статус-проверка), но... Вот я о чём подумал.
Сейчас, как я уже сказал, у нас две статьи, и для каждой из них выделен отдельный адрес:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

И какой правильный? Вообще, по идее, — то, которое заканчивается на gen-ai-policy (chatGpt — частный случай genAI), но ведь если мы возьмём его, а второй — удалим, то все старые ссылки на gpt-policy станут битыми! А ссылок на старый адрес было ой как много, ведь он существует с декабря 2022 года, и бездарные ИИ-ответы — весьма больная тема, по крайней мере годик назад их было довольно много. Было бы круто, если бы разработчики сделали бы перенаправление со старого адреса на новый — но будет ли кто-то этим заниматься?
И так, какой адрес следует выбрать?
